# Expose database via web interface

Tags: database, web-applications

I have several big database ( from 200 mb to 7 gb ) containing information pertaining an academic project.

I need to expose some statistical data about these database to my coworkers. Unfortunately I've a very strong background in mathematics and statistic but I'm not a Computer Scientist.

I would like to have something like a CMS where there are templates of the most useful informations, plus the ability from the user to generate new pages using custom templates, via an interface as intuitive as possible. Pages must be generated dynamically if they don't exist yet, or taken from cache if already calculated, to save CPU (some charts take weeks to be computed).

I have no constraints on tools, I can use whatever database format I want and whatever language is best. Now the databases are built via a python script.

I would like to keep complexity as low as possible, as I would like to concentrate on the statistical part rather than the technical part.

Which framework do you think is best suited for my needs? Could anyone point me towards the easiest, most intuitive and reliable solution?

Cheers,

Comment: if you can port the db data to mysql port it there then use phpmyadmin?

Comment: MySql + phpMYadmin was the only solution I found. I was wondering if there wasn't something else.

Comment: you can also try porting it to postgres then using pgadmin :) same banana(although pgadmin is an application, not a web app) so i guess not that same of a banana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Mysql + phpmyadmin or if you want an application instead of a web app, postgres + [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

Oh mysql also has an app if you're using a mac(and your colleagues): [SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)